# finding a word in a line in R

Tags: r, file-io, line

I have read a .txt file in R, the text was delimited by tabs and \n. What I want is to find the line number in which I can find the word "Delimiter1", and extract that information until "Delimiter2". 
The problem here is that the word is enclosed in format:

```
    \tab \tab \n
    Delimiter1 from data\tab\tab\n
    \tab\tab\data1 \tab data2 \n
    \tab\tab\data2  \tab data2 \n
    .....
    Delimiter2 from data\tab\tab\n
     ......
```

I have tried pmatch(), but no luck at all. This is a rough draft of the schema:

```
    fileName="text_all.txt"
    conn=file(fileName,open="r")
    line=readLines(conn)
    tabd<-strsplit(line,"\t")
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the actual words "Delimiter1" and "Delimiter2"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to find in which line is the word Delimiter1 and from that extract numerical data until the word Delimiter2

Comment: You might want to update your example then because 'Delimiter2' never shows up in it...

Comment: Use `grep` to find the indices `x` and `y` of `Delimiter1` and `Delimiter2`. `Then do lines[x:y]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nograpes already suggested, you can use code along these lines:

```
line[grep("Delimiter1", line, fixed = TRUE):grep("Delimiter2", line, fixed = TRUE)]
```

Each `grep` should return the index of the line containing the named delimiter. The `fixed` parameter ensures that you don't have to worry about special regular expression syntax in your delimiter strings. If either string is found more than once, the code will break.

Answer (score 2):

If your delimiters are unique (as it seems), you may use e.g. this function:

```
#' Text between delimiters
#' @param x character vector
#' @param tag1 start delimiter
#' @param tag2 stop delimiter
#' @return character vector
lines.between.tags <- function(x, tag1, tag2)
    x[do.call(seq, as.list(grep(paste(tag1, tag2, sep = '|'), x)))]
```

Simple example:

```
> text <- c('foo', 'Delimiter1 from data \t \n', 1:5, 'Delimiter2 from data \t \n', 'bar')
> lines.between.tags(text, 'Delimiter1', 'Delimiter2')
[1] "Delimiter1 from data \t \n" "1"                         
[3] "2"                          "3"                         
[5] "4"                          "5"                         
[7] "Delimiter2 from data \t \n"
```